# window.location.reload() logout authenticated user

Tags: html, node.js, passport-local

I have a button that reloads page. But it logouts user when pressed and sends to homepage. I'm using passport-local to authenticate user.
My button in html:

```
 <button onclick="window.location.reload();" class="btn btn-success">Reload</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. How do you check if user is logged in?
2. Do you save your user's logged in status in storage or cookie?

Maybe you should save your user's logged in status in storage/cookie, and check user status from storage/cookie, then refreshing will not log user out. FYI.

Comment: I'm saving it in cookie. app.post("/login",passport.authenticate("local", { failureRedirect: "back" }),function(req,res){
  res.redirect(req.body.siteName);
});

Comment: Checking if user logged in using  req.isAuthenticated()

Comment: And it's ok when I'm pressing reload button in browser or navigate to other pages it stays  in logged in status

Comment: Oh sorry, I just didn't put type of button, changed it type="button" and started working normally

Comment: @AkbaraliBekmurodov Glad you solved the problem ^_^